# ModuleNotFoundError from Docker container with Gunicorn

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm learning how dockerize a Django project. So, I've created a simple hello world with Django.
After this I've created my Dockerfile:

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1

# Official Ubuntu Image as Layer
FROM ubuntu:20.04 as os
# Disable Prompt During Packages Installation
ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
# Update&Upgrade Ubuntu
RUN apt update && apt upgrade -y

# OS as Layer
FROM os as gis-os
# Disable Prompt During Packages Installation
ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
# Set Python environment variables
# Prevents Python from writing pyc files to disc
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
# Prevents Python from buffering stdout and stderr
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
# Install python and upgrade pip
RUN apt install -y python3-pip build-essential
RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip
# Installing Geospatial libraries
RUN apt install -y libpq-dev
# Install PROJ
RUN apt install -y libproj-dev proj-data proj-bin unzip
# Install GEOS
RUN apt install -y libgeos-dev
# Install GDAL
RUN apt install -y tzdata
RUN apt install -y libgdal-dev python3-gdal gdal-bin

# GIS-OS as Layer
FROM gis-os as djangoproject
# Update&Upgrade Layer
RUN apt update && apt upgrade -y
# Set work directory
WORKDIR /app
# Copy project data
COPY . ./djangodocker
# Create staticfiles directory
RUN mkdir -p static-folder
# Create media directory
RUN mkdir -p media-folder
# Install project dependencies
RUN pip3 install --no-cache-dir -r ./djangodocker/requirements.txt
## Active entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /app/djangodocker/entrypoint.sh
# Run entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/app/djangodocker/entrypoint.sh"]

# DJANGOPROJECT as Layer
FROM djangoproject as gunicorn-setting-up
# Update&Upgrade Layer
RUN apt update && apt upgrade -y
# Install Gunicorn
RUN pip3 install gunicorn
```

NB: My goal is to obtain a Geodjango project, so I need many stuff related to GIS field.

Alongside Dockerfile I've the `entrypoint.sh`.

Below the docker-compose file:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  website:
    container_name: web_project
    image: dev-project/django
    build: djangodocker
    restart: always
    env_file: dev.env
    command: python3 djangodocker/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
```

When I run `sudo docker-compose -f docker-compose-dev.yml up -d --build` I can navigate inside my project. But when I use:

```
command: gunicorn djangodocker.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000
```

Instead of:

```
command: python3 djangodocker/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

I see the error below:

```
web_project | [2021-11-14 15:28:01 +0000] [1] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
web_project | [2021-11-14 15:28:01 +0000] [1] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8000 (1)
web_project | [2021-11-14 15:28:01 +0000] [1] [INFO] Using worker: sync
web_project | [2021-11-14 15:28:01 +0000] [9] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 9
web_project | [2021-11-14 15:28:01 +0000] [9] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
web_project | Traceback (most recent call last):
web_project |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 589, in spawn_worker
web_project |     worker.init_process()
web_project |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 134, in init_process
web_project |     self.load_wsgi()
web_project |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 146, in load_wsgi
web_project |     self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
web_project |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
web_project |     self.callable = self.load()
web_project |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 58, in load
web_project |     return self.load_wsgiapp()
web_project |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 48, in load_wsgiapp
web_project |     return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
web_project |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 359, in import_app
web_project |     mod = importlib.import_module(module)
web_project |   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
web_project |     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
web_project |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
web_project |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
web_project |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 973, in _find_and_load_unlocked
web_project | ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'djangodocker.wsgi'
web_project | [2021-11-14 15:28:01 +0000] [9] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 9)
web_project | [2021-11-14 15:28:01 +0000] [1] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
web_project | [2021-11-14 15:28:01 +0000] [1] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
```

The image below shows the project tree.
It is my first project with Docker, I don't understand why Gunicorn can't see `djangodocker.wsgi`, I've tried with `djangodocker.djangodocker.wsgi` without fortune.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was in `command`:

```
command: sh -c "cd djangodocker/ &&
                gunicorn djangodocker.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000"
```

I've solved using the instruction above.